# Join on unnested integer array column and count occurrences in array

Tags: postgresql, join, count, array

I am trying to join two tables after I have unnested one of them. The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE teachers (id SERIAL, first_name VARCHAR(60), last_name VARCHAR(60));
```

```
CREATE TABLE training_modules (id SERIAL, course VARCHAR(60), teachers_id INTEGER[]);
```

I want to write a query that will return the teachers names and the number of training_modules they've participated in (a count of their IDs), like so:

```
teacher_name  id_count
bob teacher   4
sally lady    3
jimbo jones   5
```

So far, I've been able to get a count of each ID with this query:

```
SELECT tid, count(*) as id_count
FROM training_modules tm, unnest(tm.teachers_id) as tid
GROUP BY tid;
```

All fine and good. I tried to apply that to another query, where I join the teachers table, and it doesn't work as expected. This query:

```
SELECT t.id, concat(t.first_name, ' ', t.last_name) AS teacher_name, tm.id_count
FROM (
   SELECT unnest(training_modules.teachers_id) AS id_count, count(*)
   FROM training_modules
   GROUP BY id_count
   ) AS tm
INNER JOIN teachers t ON tm.id_count = t.id;
```

Results in the table below, where the `id_count` column is no longer a count, but returns the same value as the `t.id` column.

```
 id |     t_name      | tc 
----+-----------------+----
  5 | Jimbo Jones     |  5
  4 | Frank McGee     |  4
  6 | Sara Sarason    |  6
  2 | Joshua Jesps    |  2
  1 | Larry Bucatin   |  1
  3 | Natalie Fatali  |  3
```

Any help to get the right count appearing while joining the tables would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you attached the column alias to the wrong expression in your 2nd query.

```
SELECT id, concat_ws(' ', t.first_name, t.last_name) AS teacher_name, tm.id_count
FROM  (
   SELECT unnest(tm.teachers_id) AS id, count(*) AS id_count
   FROM   training_modules tm
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) AS tm
JOIN   teachers t USING (id);
```

Aside:
`concat_ws(' ', t.first_name, t.last_name)` is typically better, as it only adds the separator where it makes sense (when both `first_name` & `last_name` are `NOT NULL`).

Comment: Thanks! For both the solution and the tip! Much appreciated!